# Maximize user control that inherit master page(form)

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, master-pages, fullscreen

I have master page that is form in C# windows application. in master page , I set many panels and button.one of them(panels) is master panel. in run time ,program(master page that is form) is maximize, when clicked button , user control is put in master panel. but isn't maximize!!!! 
How to Maximize user control in run time?

in master page

```
private void bntContentEnter_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UserControlEnter_Parking u = new UserControlEnter_Parking();

            MasterPanel.Controls.Clear();
            ShowFullScreen(u);
            MasterPanel.Controls.Add(u);
        }


 private void ShowFullScreen(UserControl userControl)
        {
            Form fullScreenForm = new Form();
            fullScreenForm.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
            fullScreenForm.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            fullScreenForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
            userControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            fullScreenForm.Controls.Add(userControl);
            fullScreenForm.Show();
        }
```

Comment: What are you referring to as a "master page"? Do you mean to say you're using a multiple document interface?

Comment: No. I add new form and rename to masterPage!!! and add this panel. and navigate between user control with panel. but in run time user control that renamed mastePanel didn't show!!!!!!!

Comment: You only want to maximize usercontrol? It is easy, but you should keep it in master panel and not add it directly to your Form? Am i clear?